# SELECT a partial value found within other values in the same column?

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a database that contains values from physical barcodes in a column, and the barcodes are proprietary from a 3rd party vendor. The barcode format has a leading character that's part of the physical barcode when scanned directly, but the vendor interface for the customer (me) strips the leading character. For example, if I scan the barcode directly into whatever software I'm using, the value may be 'X12345' or 'Y12345' or 'Z12345', but if I pull the barcode value for any of these items from the vendor interface, I will only get '12345'.

I can have multiple items (rows) that correctly share the same barcode. But my database sometimes has the directly-scanned value with the leading character, and sometimes the value pulled from the vendor's interface without the leading character, all in the same BARCODE column.

I want to begin cleanup efforts by finding all rows that have the numeric-only barcode and any of the same barcode that also has the leading character.

I'd like to run a SELCT statement that searches the BARCODE column and returns rows with BARCODE values like:

```
12345
X12345
Y12345
Z12345
67890
X67890
Y67890
Z67890
etc.
```

I'm trying to figure out a SELECT statement WHERE [BARCODE] LIKE '_'+[BARCODE], but it's only returning a couple values that start with the % wildcard. (These two values are errors, so I'm glad I found them, but it's not what I was hoping for.) Thanks!

Comment: Please read this document on how to ask a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you want to clean up, can't you just look for all barcodes that start with a letter and remove that letter?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, there are other clean up tasks to do that are related, but not part of the query I'm trying to build. I'm using the groups of records with these similar barcodes to identify the rows that we need to focus on.

Comment: As you are using the tool SSMS, I guess you are using the DBMS SQL Server? (I don't know whether SSMS is only for this DBMS or for others, too.)

Answer (score 1):

You want to select rows for which at least one other row for the same barcode exists. Your idea with `LIKE '_XXXX'` is good, but you'll want to look at two different rows. You can use `EXISTS` for this.

One simple option:

```
select *
from mytable t1
where exists
(
  select null
  from mytable t2
  where t2.barcode like '_' + t1.barcode
     or t1.barcode like '_' + t2.barcode
)
order by reverse(barcode);
```

Another option is to remove the letter to get a key:

```
with 
  with_key as
  (
    select t.*, trim(leading 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' from barcode) as key
    from mytable t
  ),
  dup_keys as
  (
    select key
    from with_key
    group by key
    having count(*) > 1
  )
select *
from with_key
where key in (select key from dup_keys)
order by key;
```

Comment: Ha, well I ran the first query overnight, and I had to kill it this morning because it locked the db. I'll try out the second (but not leave it overnight).

Comment: Sorry to hear that. It may be an option to add a stripped-barcode column to the table that you fill with the trimmed value of the second query. Thus you wouldn't have to calculate it on-the-fly. And you could even create an index on that column. If the first query ran for hours, the same may happen to the second one, so persisting the key and speeding things up with an index might actually be the best approach now.